# How to write a regex pattern in php for an html5 form numeric input validation?

Tags: php, regex, html

I have a form in which there are many form fields which are dynamically being generated and I am trying to limit a numeric input field to a minimum and maximum value via the following code which isn't working in firefox

```
    $products=getAllProducts();//an array of product objects
    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
    for($i=0;$i<(count($products));$i++){
        echo '<label>'.$products[$i].getName().'</label>';
        echo '<input type="number" pattern="\d*" min="1" max="'.$products[$i].getAvailableQty().'" name="'.$products[$i].getId().'"></input>';

    }
    echo '<input id="cartButton" type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="cart.php" />';
    echo '</form>';
```

Some one suggested me to use regular expressions but I don't know how to write a regular expression each time for a different a min value as 1 and max value as `$products[$i].getAvailableQty()` value.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding. If you are just trying to make sure a user does not enter a value higher than the available quantity, RegEx is not necessary in this case. Just validate the inputted quantity after the form is submitted, or using javascript.

Comment: I want it to be validated on the client side even when the java-script is turned off!

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/29 it is supported in recent release.

Comment: It can be different each type depending on the `$products[$i].getName()`,`$products[$i].getAvailableQty()`,`$products[$i].getId()`...e.g.
`<form method="POST" action=""><label>Camera</label><input type="number" pattern="\d*" min="1" max="5" name="p-27"></input>
<label>Keyboard</label><input type="number" pattern="\d*" min="1" max="3" name="p-31"></input>
<input id="cartButton" type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="cart.php" />

</form>`

Comment: <input type="number"> is an HTML5 element that not all browsers support. So if you want browser compatibilities, you may have to go the Javascript route.

Comment: You can create complicated logic to generate regex, but its not that simple. I just give samples for 1,2,3-digit `max` numbers and `min=0` to understand the complexity. `7 => ^[0-7]$`, `36 => ^\d|[1-2]\d|3[0-6]$`, `531 => ^\d{1,2}|[1-4]\d{2}|5[0-2]\d|53[0-1]`.

Comment: Another suggestion for cross-browser compatibility is to use a combobox with the various quantity in the list of options. Of course this is only viable if the maximum quantity is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function for getting the regular expression

```
function getInputValidationRegex($qty){
    $qtyCopy=$qty;
    $regexpArr=array();
    $noOfDigits=strlen((String)$qty);

    for($i=1;$i<=$noOfDigits;$i++){
        if($i<$noOfDigits){
            $str='';

            if($i==1)
                $str.='[1-9]';
            else
                $str.='[0-9]{1,'.($i-1).'}';


        $regexpArr[]=$str;
        }
        if($i==$noOfDigits){
            $str='';
            for($k=1;$k<=$i;$k++){
                $lastDigit=$qtyCopy%10;
                $qtyCopy=floor($qtyCopy/10);
                if($k==$i){
                    $str2='[1-'.$lastDigit.']'.$str;
                    $str=$str2;
                }
                else{
                    $str2='[0-'.$lastDigit.']'.$str;
                    $str=$str2;
                }

            }
            $regexpArr[]=$str;
        }

    }
    return implode("|",$regexpArr);

}
```

and modify your code as follows

```
 $products=getAllProducts();//an array of product objects
    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';
    for($i=0;$i<(count($products));$i++){
        echo '<label>'.$products[$i].getName().'</label>';
        echo '<input type="number" pattern="'.getInputValidationRegex($products[$i].getAvailableQty()).'" name="'.$products[$i].getId().'"></input>';

    }
    echo '<input id="cartButton" type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="cart.php" />';
    echo '</form>';
```